# Подключение к Instagram

Tags: java, android, instagram

Использую `webview` во фрагменте.

**Вот код фрагмента:**

```
public class AuthFragment extends Fragment {

    private String mUrl;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private WebView mWebView;
    private LinearLayout mLayout;
    private TextView mTitle;
    private OAuthListener mListener;
    private Context mContext;

    static final int MARGIN = 4;
    static final int PADDING = 2;
    static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams FILL = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    private static final String TAG = "AuthFragment";

    public AuthFragment(Context context, String url,
                        OAuthListener listener) {
        mUrl = url;
        mListener = listener;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mProgressDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.progress_dialog_message));

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_auth, container, false);
        mLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.auth_fragment_container);
        setUpTitle();
        setUpWebView();

        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getActivity());
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
        return view;
    }

    /**
     *
     */

    private void setUpTitle() {
        mTitle = new TextView(getActivity());
        mTitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        mTitle.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        mTitle.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        mTitle.setPadding(MARGIN + PADDING, MARGIN, MARGIN, MARGIN);
        mLayout.addView(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    private void setUpWebView() {
        mWebView = new WebView(getActivity());
        mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new OAuthWebViewClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);
        mWebView.setLayoutParams(FILL);
        mLayout.addView(mWebView);
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    private class OAuthWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Redirecting URL " + url);
            String redirectUrl = getResources().getString(R.string.redirect_url);

            if (url.startsWith(redirectUrl)) {

                String urls[] = url.split("=");
                mListener.onComplete(urls[1]);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);

            Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + error);
            mListener.onError(error.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            Log.d(TAG, "Loading URL: " + url);

            mProgressDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            String title = mWebView.getTitle();
            if( (title != null) && (title.length() > 0) ) {
                mTitle.setText(title);
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onPageFinished URL: " + url);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public interface OAuthListener {
        public abstract void onComplete(String requestToken);
        public abstract void onError(String error);
    }


}
```

Дальше использую класс:

```
public class InstagramAPI {

    private String mAuthUrl;
    private String mTokenUrl;
    private String mAccessToken;
    private Context mCtx;
    private String mClientId;
    private String mClientSecret;
    private String mRegirectUrl;
    private InstagramSession mSession;

    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    private static String TAG = "InstagramAPI";

    AuthFragment.OAuthListener mListener;

    /**
     *
     */
    public static String mRedirectUrl = "";
    private static final String AUTH_URL = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/";
    private static final String TOKEN_URL = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token";
    private static final String API_URL = "https://api.instagram.com/v1";

    public InstagramAPI(final Context context,
                        String clientId, String clientSecret,
                        String redirectUrl) {

        mCtx = context;
        mClientId = clientId;
        mClientSecret = clientSecret;
        mRegirectUrl = redirectUrl;
        mSession = new InstagramSession(mCtx);

        mTokenUrl = TOKEN_URL + "?client_id=" + clientId + "&client_secret="
                + clientSecret + "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUrl
                + "&grant_type=authorization_code";

        mAuthUrl = AUTH_URL
                + "?client_id="
                + clientId
                + "&redirect_uri="
                + mRegirectUrl
                + "&response_type=code&display=touch&scope=likes+comments+relationships";


        mListener = new AuthFragment.OAuthListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String requestToken) {
                Toast.makeText(context, requestToken, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i(TAG, "GET Access");
                if (!requestToken.isEmpty()) {
                    getAccessToken(requestToken);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Ой что-то пошло не так!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String error) {

            }
        };

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    public AuthFragment getAuthFragment() {

        return  new AuthFragment(mCtx, mAuthUrl, mListener);
    }

    private void getAccessToken(final String requestToken) {

        mProgressDialog.setMessage(mCtx.getResources().getString(R.string.progress_dialog_message));


        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {


            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                try {

                    URL url = new URL(mTokenUrl);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Opening Token URL " + url);

                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    //urlConnection.connect();
                    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                    writer.write("client_id=" + mClientId + "&client_secret="
                            + mClientSecret + "&grant_type=authorization_code"
                            + "&redirect_uri=" + mRedirectUrl + "&code=" + requestToken);
                    writer.flush();

                    Log.i(TAG, "RESPONSE: " + urlConnection.getInputStream().toString());

                    String response = streamToString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                    Log.i(TAG, "Response " + response);

                    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
                    mAccessToken = jsonObject.getString("access_token");
                    Log.i(TAG, "Got access token: " + mAccessToken);

                    String userId = jsonObject.getJSONObject("user").getString("id");
                    String userName = jsonObject.getJSONObject("user").getString("username");
                    String userFullName = jsonObject.getJSONObject("user").getString("full_name");


                    mSession.storeUserData(mAccessToken, userId, userName, userFullName);

                    Log.i(TAG, "User id: " + userId);
                    Log.i(TAG, "User Name: " + userName);
                    Log.i(TAG, "User Full Name: " + userFullName);



                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i(TAG, "ERROR 1!");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i(TAG, "ERROR 3!");
                } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e(TAG, "ERROR 3!");
                }

                return null;
            }


        }.execute();



    }
}
```

Тут возникает исключение `IOException`.

Comment: покажите стактрейс ошибки, и на какой строке она возникает

Comment: Исключение выбрасывает эта строка  HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();  Не получается открыть соединение. Просмотрел код раз двадцать.

Comment: а стактрейс где?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bw2WlTC9y8P3b05PcjJFamhDMTQ

Comment: Сюда стактрейс вставьте

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token

Comment: at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:194)    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)   at com.tomsk.shukur.testinstagram.instagramHelper.InstagramAPI$2.doInBackground(InstagramAPI.java:155)  at com.tomsk.shukur.testinstagram.instagramHelper.InstagramAPI$2.doInBackground(InstagramAPI.java:133)

Comment: at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)

Comment: вставьте стактрейс в вопрос целиком, и огтформатируйте его. А для начала убедитесь, что у прилодения есть разрешение на доступ в интернет